# Slow SP call through LINQ or SqlCommand, but not with EXECUTE

Tags: asp.net, linq, performance, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I have a fairly complex Strored Procedure in MS SQL Server, which queries large database. I done many optimization, so when I call it with EXECUTE from SSMS it runs under 1 sec, witch good enough.

Problem is when I call it from ASP.NET 3.5 using LINQ or SqlCommand it takes several minutes on the production server, while the server load is not even high.

I think it has something to do with the configuration, bec the development server runs as expected.

The production server has SQL Express 2008 sp2, the development server has SQL Express 2005. My dev machine has SQL Express 2008 R2 and performs well.

What/where should I check?

ty!

Comment: Have you tried using the SQL Server profiler to see what SQL is actually being sent to the production server?  Also, have you compared the query plans for the same stored procedure in development and production?

Comment: @R0MANARMY:
Audit Login;
RPC:Complete (Duration: 1231);
Audit Logout (Duration: 1236);

Test .aspx only have a gridview, nothing else and codebehind only have the sp call, and runs for almost 3 minutes if I set the timeout high enough.

Comment: If you run the query from SSMS against production, it still finishes in 1 minute?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: yes, the bottom right corner says 00:00:01.

Comment: Did you try using l2sprof that Francis recommended to see what's actually being sent to SQL server, etc?  Also, have you looked at whether the slowness is due to the query itself or something to do with the environment, connection to DB server taking longer to establish or other overhead?

Comment: Sounds like a rogue query plan -- have you another instance that would allow you to run the stored procedure via a linked server (i.e. `exec production.mydb.myschema.myprocedure` from another instance) - it will probably perform "as badly" as via a `SqlCommand`

Answer (score 1):

Check this with SQL Profiler. LINQ to SQL will most probably suffer from the Select n + 1 issue.

Have a quick look here for that:
http://l2sprof.com/Learn/Alerts/SelectNPlusOne

Comment: Unfortunetly no, I tested the sp call in a separate page and still slow. It returns list of ints.